# From within a Report go to a spesific record on subform using DAO

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I want a user to click on a hyperlink in a Report and then navigate to a specific record that is located in a sub form

[This](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=183379) thread works great by using Docmd.openform and passing OpenArg parameters but what if you would like more functionality or have multiple parameters you wish to pass?

I got the following code in the report hyperlink field using DAO that I can't get working:

```
    Private Sub Text209_Click()
        ''open specific journal entry
        DoCmd.OpenForm "BatchJ Form"
        Forms![BatchJ Form]![Journal Form].SetFocus ''set focus to subform journal

        ''now find the journal entry
        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

        'Get the database and Recordset
        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Journal Tbl", dbOpenDynaset)

        'Search for the first matching record
        rst.FindFirst "[Journal ID] = " & CLng(Me.CrJournal)
        Forms![BatchJ Form]![Journal Form].Recordset.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark ''this line gives me an error: "Object doesn't support this object or method"

        ''cleanup
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set dbs = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: If I change the line with the error to :  "Forms![BatchJ Form]![Journal Form].Form.Recordset.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark" then I get this error "not a valid bookmark"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are looking for something like this:

```
Private Sub Text209_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    ''open specific journal entry
    DoCmd.OpenForm "BatchJ Form"
    Forms![BatchJ Form]![Journal Form].SetFocus ''set focus to subform journal

    ''now find the journal entry
    Set rst = Forms![BatchJ Form]![Journal Form].Form.RecordsetClone
    'Search for the first matching record
    rst.FindFirst "[Journal ID] = " & CLng(Me.CrJournal)
    Forms![BatchJ Form]![Journal Form].Form.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

    ''cleanup
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```